# How to wait until a scene is fully loaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I need to wait until a scene is fully loaded in order to move a `gameObject` to it from `DontDestroyOnLoad` scene. If I do it too soon (just after calling `SceneManager.LoadScene()`) then the `gameObject` disappears. Based on [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1076926/wait-load-scene-until-finish-load-menu.html) I implemented a scene loading class to solve this issue:

```
public static class CustomSceneManager
{
    public delegate void SceneChange(string sceneName);

    public static event SceneChange LoadScene;
    public static event SceneChange UnloadScene;

    private static IEnumerator LoadLevel (string sceneName){
        var asyncLoadLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        while (!asyncLoadLevel.isDone){
            Debug.Log("Loading the Scene"); 
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static void OnLoadScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        OnUnloadScene(newSceneName);
        LoadLevel(newSceneName);
        LoadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }
    private static void OnUnloadScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        UnloadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }
}
```

I'm calling two events from it (`LoadScene` and `UnloadScene`). However the `LoadLevel(newSceneName)` doesn't work - it simply doesn't load a scene. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Now I'm passing the `MonoBehavior` reference of the script calling `OnLoadScene` methid like this:

```
    public static void OnLoadScene(MonoBehaviour loader, string newSceneName)
    {
        UnloadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
        loader.StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(newSceneName));
        Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name); // this line returns previous scene
        LoadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }
```

Now the scene loads, but when I check what scene is currently loaded, it returns the previous scene name.

EDIT 2:

To be more precise I replaced `Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` with `Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(newSceneName).isLoaded);` and it returns `False`.

Comment: You have to run coroutienes using `StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(newSceneName);`

Comment: @derHugo this is a static class though. Is there any other way?

Comment: @derHugo thanks, that helped with loading the scene but it seems that the coroutine isn't working properly.

Comment: Doesn't ```SceneManager``` have a ```SceneLoaded``` event?

Comment: @Immersive Based on my testing it's called before the scene is fully loaded and because of that moving a `gameObject` to that scene doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run coroutienes using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

You either would need to pass in a reference of a `MonoBehaviour` that will execute the coroutine or simply make your class a Singleton that is never destroyed

Than actually you will invoke your event too early when it is not yet loaded but you just started to load it so rather do e.g.

```
public class CustomSceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void SceneChange(string sceneName);

    public static event SceneChange LoadScene;
    public static event SceneChange UnloadScene;

    private CustomNetworkManager singleton;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(singleton && singleton != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        singleton = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }
    
    private static IEnumerator LoadLevel (string sceneName){
        var asyncLoadLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        while (!asyncLoadLevel.isDone){
            Debug.Log("Loading the Scene"); 
            yield return null;
        }

        LoadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }
    
    public static void OnLoadScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        if(! singleton)
        {
            singleton = new GameObject("CustomNetworkManager").AddComponent<CustomNetworkManager>();
        }

        OnUnloadScene(newSceneName);
        singleton.StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(newSceneName));
    }
```

Comment: I want to keep the class static. I still have an issue with the coroutine, I updated the question.

Comment: Your newest edit is obviously wrong .. see my 3th sentence in this answer. The `StartCoroutine` does **not** delay the calling methods execution so you execute the other two lines before the new scene is loaded .. you have to move that to the end of the `IEnumerator` or alternatively pass it in as callback .. you can see that I call the `LoadScene?.Invoke()` at the end of the routine

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is with an async method.

The catch is that in order to await an **AsyncOperation** you need a custom awaiter class. There are a few libraries that make it possible, and my favorite one is [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask).

```
using Cysharp.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class CustomSceneManager
{
    public delegate void SceneChange(string sceneName);

    public static event SceneChange LoadScene;
    public static event SceneChange UnloadScene;

    private static async UniTask LoadLevelAsync(string sceneName)
    {
        await SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }

    public static async UniTask OnLoadSceneAsync(string newSceneName)
    {
        OnUnloadScene(newSceneName);
        await LoadLevelAsync(newSceneName);
        LoadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }

    private static void OnUnloadScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        UnloadScene?.Invoke(newSceneName);
    }
}
```